# What does base of 2-dimensional array mean?

Tags: f#

What does base of 2-dimensional array mean? What does zero - based array mean? There is not a single word about it in MSDN.

Comment: As it stands it's going to be difficult to fully answer your question, you will need to provide some additional context, for example I can't see why you've tagged this question as F#, how do these questions relate to F#? NB: Usually a zero based array means an array were the first element is element 0 not element 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the lower bound of the array:

```
let matrix : int [,]= Array2D.zeroCreateBased 10 20 5 7
for x in 10..14 do
    for y in 20..26 do
        printfn "%A" matrix.[x, y]
```

you can obtain the lower and upper bounds this way:

```
let x1 = matrix.GetLowerBound 0 
let x2 = matrix.GetUpperBound 0
let y1 = matrix.GetLowerBound 1
let y2 = matrix.GetUpperBound 1
```

or like this:

```
let x1 = Array2D.base1   matrix   
let x2 = Array2D.length1 matrix + x1 - 1    
let y1 = Array2D.base2   matrix  
let y2 = Array2D.length2 matrix + y1 - 1   

printfn "%A" (x1, y1) // (10, 20)
printfn "%A" (x2, y2) // (14, 26)
```

Zero based mean that they first element index is 0